# Select in LINQ all keys from List of List of KeyValuePairs

Tags: c#, linq, distinct-values

I have a List of List of KeyValuePairs which I would like to bring to a standard form and further export it as a table. To do this I need to get all unique Keys present in the list. How can I get the unique keys with LINQ?

My source data has this form:

```
var sourceData = new List<List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>>();

...

var uniqueKeyNames = sourceData.SomeLinqCodeHere....
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It sounds like you just need a combination of `SelectMany`, `Select` and `Distinct`:

```
var allKeys = sourceData.SelectMany(list => list) // Flatten to a sequence of KVP
                        .Select(kvp => kvp.Key)   // Select just the keys
                        .Distinct();
```

Note that if you want to iterate over `allKeys` more than once, you probably want to materialize the query, e.g. by calling `ToList` at the end:

```
var allKeys = sourceData.SelectMany(list => list) // Flatten to a sequence of KVP
                        .Select(kvp => kvp.Key)   // Select just the keys
                        .Distinct()
                        .ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var uniqueKeyNames = sourceData.SelectMany(l => l).Select(kv => kv.Key).Distinct();
```